# SQL query to get a result based on count of records in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in MySQL DB: *orders*, *items* and *item_to_orders*. That last table, item_to_orders, ties orders and items together by item_id and order_id indexes.

**orders:**

```
order_id   order_name   order_status
    1         Test           0
    2         Test2          1
```

**items:**

```
item_id    item_name
    1        item1
    2        item2
```

**item_to_order**

```
order_id   item_id
   1          1
   2          2
```

I need to select one *item_id* from *items* table, that has no orders with *order_status=0* assigned to it in *item_to_order* table. It can have any other orders (where order_status != 0) assigned to it  or no orders at all.

**Updated:** I was trying to use this query, but it seems that it doesn't give me all the correct results (I added LIMIT because I need only 1 item of that kind).

```
SELECT ei.item_id from items ei
LEFT JOIN items_to_orders eio ON ei.item_id=eio.item_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select * from orders o where o.order_id = eio.order_id and o.order_status=0)
ORDER BY ei.item_id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: So you want to select an item only when *not exists* a certain kind of order for it. What did you try? Where did you fail?

Comment: What should be your final result ?

Comment: In my example, my final result should be item_id that has no orders with order_status=0 to its name - so in that case, I want the result to be 2 (an item_id that meets that requirement)

Comment: @Viceromag: Have you tried anything and got stuck or is it simply that you want others do the work for you? Did you get my hint?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Yes, I got your hint and I'm trying something like this -  SELECT ei.item_id from items ei LEFT JOIN items_to_orders eio ON ei.item_id=eio.item_id where not exists (select * from orders o where o.order_id = eio.order_id and o.order_status=0) ORDER BY ei.item_id LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is already quite fine. `EXISTS` is the way to go. Only you don't want to see *item/order* combinations for which not exists a certain order type, but *items*. So you must put `items_to_orders` inside the subquery, so you select from *items* for which not exists the order type.

```
select item_id 
from items i
where not exists 
(
  select * 
  from items_to_orders ito
  join orders o on o.order_id = ito.order_id 
  where ito.item_id = i.item_id
  and o.order_status = 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name
 FROM order o
 JOIN item_to_order ir ON(ir.order_id = o.order_id)
 JOIN items i ON(i.item_id =ir.item_id)
 WHERE o.order_status!=0
 GROUP BY i.item_id
```